# Groovy: Get duration in years

Tags: date, groovy, duration

On running the following code in groovy -

```
import groovy.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory
def today = new Date()
use(TimeCategory)
{
  def modifiedToday = today.plus(10.minutes)
  modifiedToday = modifiedToday.plus(10.months)
  modifiedToday = modifiedToday.plus(10.years)
  def duration = modifiedToday - today
  println duration.years
  println duration.months
  println duration.days
  println duration.minutes
}
```

I am getting the following output -

```
0
0
3956
10
```

Please suggest, why am I getting years and months as 0 and all the value in days. How do I get the value in years and months?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would you get it in months?

Each month has a different number of days, so what would you do?

You can get back the date this represents from now by doing:

```
println duration.from.now
```

Or, you can get the date that represents in the past by doing:

```
println duration.ago
```

And I guess you could work it out from there, but there is no in-built functionality for normalising a TimeDuration based on a given date

---

### Edit

This sort of thing rolls from one date in the past to the specified date.  I haven't done any real testing on it though, so you should take care and test the life out of it before using it in anything important...

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*
import groovy.time.DatumDependentDuration
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

DatumDependentDuration getAge( Date dob, Date now = new Date() ) {
  dob.clearTime()
  now.clearTime()
  assert dob < now
  Calendar.instance.with { c ->
    c.time = dob
    def (years, months, days) = [ 0, 0, 0 ]
   
    while( ( c[ YEAR ] < now[ YEAR ] - 1 ) || 
           ( c[ YEAR ] < now[ YEAR ] && c[ MONTH ] <= now[ MONTH ] ) ) {
      c.add( YEAR, 1 )
      years++
    }

    while( ( c[ YEAR ] < now[ YEAR ] ) ||
           ( c[ MONTH ] < now[ MONTH ] && c[ DAY_OF_MONTH ] <= now[ DAY_OF_MONTH ] ) ) {
      // Catch when we are wrapping the DEC/JAN border and would end up beyond now
      if( c[ YEAR ] == now[ YEAR ] - 1 &&
          now[ MONTH ] == JANUARY && c[ MONTH ] == DECEMBER &&
          c[ DAY_OF_MONTH ] > now[ DAY_OF_MONTH ] ) {
        break
      }
      c.add( MONTH, 1 )
      months++
    }

    while( c[ DAY_OF_YEAR ] != now[ DAY_OF_YEAR ] ) {
      c.add( DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 )
      days++
    }
    
    new DatumDependentDuration( years, months, days, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
  }
}

println getAge( Date.parse( 'dd/MM/yyyy', '11/10/2000' ) )

// Prints: '12 years, 2 months, 30 days'
```

Comment: +1 "Each month has a different number of days, so what would you do?"

Comment: For example, let's say, I want to calculate the age (on this day) in years/months/days for a person and I have his date of birth with me.

Comment: @SoftEngi Wrote a function to do that... There are probably cleaner ways, and as I said I have done minimal testing on it (The case shown is the only test, and I *believe* it is right)