# I wanto to operate with dates on grails

Tags: date, grails

I want to calculate the age of a person, I have the birth date `BD` =`java.util.Date` stored there on a variable, and I would like to get the age of the person in 1 year- 2 months - 3 days for example.

The age has to be with today's date. I'm new at grails I'm not sure how to operate with dates which variables of which type to use help me please.

Comment: [This is how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258116/2051952) you can get purely using `DatumDependentDuration`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time plugin for doing date math.