# Calculate age in Groovy from today

Tags: groovy

Trying to figure out how old someone is based on their bday. The following code gives us the number of days

```
def now = new Date()
def dob = new Date('08/21/1982')

println now - dob
```

We could divide by 365 but that isn't entirely accurate. There has to be an easy way to do this but I just can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257888/groovy-get-duration-in-years

Comment: They are both viable options but its pretty crazy to me that there is no built in way to do this. I guess since 2.3 has been released I will go with the Java 8 option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or using Java 8 and Groovy 2.3 RC (if you want to be on the bleeding edge) ;-)

```
import java.time.*

LocalDate today    = LocalDate.now()
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of( 1982, Month.AUGUST, 8 )

Period period = Period.between( birthday, today )

println """$period.years years, 
          |$period.months months, 
          |$period.days days""".stripMargin()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sleek alternative using [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) :)

```
@Grab('joda-time:joda-time:2.3')
import org.joda.time.Period
import org.joda.time.DateTime

def now = new DateTime()
def dob = new DateTime(1982, 8, 21, 0, 0)

def period = new Period(dob, now)

println """$period.years years, 
         |$period.months months, 
         |$period.days days, 
         |$period.hours hours, 
         |$period.minutes minutes
        """.stripMargin()
```

Answer (score 1):

For me joda was not available so I searched another, more groovy solution and found:

```
def duration = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(
  new Date(),//date1
  new Date(session.creationTime)//date2
);
println "seconds: " + dur2.seconds;
println "min: " + dur2.minutes;
println "hours: " + dur2.hours;
```

Comment: duration or dur2?

Answer (score 0):

```
def current = new Date()
println current
def dob = new Date ('06/27/2000')
println dob
def res = current - dob
def age = res/365
println age
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.sap.it.api.mapping.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import groovy.time.TimeCategory;
import groovy.time.TimeDuration;

def String customFunc(String DOB){
if(DOB == '')    
{
DOB = '';
return DOB;
}
else
{
Date birth_yr=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(DOB);
Date date = new Date();
def duration = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(date,birth_yr);
def age = (duration.days).intdiv(365)
return age
} 
}
```

Comment: This code will help you to take DOB from the database and using DOB as an input parameter you can calculate the age in groovy used in SAP CPI

Comment: If you have information to add then EDIT your answer and put it there. Nobody wants to read unformatted code in a comment.