# How to convert number days to years, months, days?

Tags: java, date, groovy

Yes, I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but I didn't find any solution.

The problem is to get years, months, days from days count.

Main problem is:

1 month = 30 days
  1 year = 365 days

For example:

```
30 days = 0 year, 1 month, 0 days
364 days = 0 year, 11 months, 29 days
```

And I have a problem. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
int totalDays = 364;
int daysInMonth = 30; //30.41666666666667
int onlyYears = Math.floor(totalDays/365).intValue();
int onlyMonths = Math.floor((totalDays - (onlyYears*365))/daysInMonth).intValue();
int onlyDays = totalDays - onlyMonths*daysInMonth - onlyYears*365;
println(onlyYears + ":" + onlyMonths + ":" + onlyDays);
```

So, if daysInMonth = 30 it works correctly for totalDays 30 = 1 month, 40 = 1 month and 10 days etc, but if i set totalDays to 364 code returns 12 months and 4 days, but 11 months and 29 days should be. If I set daysInMonth  to 30.41666666666667 it will correclty work for 364, but wrong for 30, 40, etc.

Comment: WHat version of Java/Groovy are you using?

Comment: Well, it is going to depend on what day and month (and year for lewap years) you're at. 30 days starting at janurary 1st, and 30 days starting at February 1st should yield different output. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Java 7, Groovy 2.4.3

Comment: Hi @Gwalk, just to get your intention - why are you asking, do you really want to solve that by hand or are you searching for a solution how to handle times and day-fractions easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate age in Groovy from today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257889/calculate-age-in-groovy-from-today)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question as asked is impossible to answer and is not a programming issue.  It is impossible to determine years, months and days purely from a count of days without a start date reference, as the number of days in each month is not a constant - therefore any constant value for `daysInMonth` will give a flawed result.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8 with Groovy, you could do:

```
import java.time.*

int totalDays = 364

Period diff = LocalDate.now().with { now ->
    Period.between(now, now.plusDays(totalDays))
}

println "$diff.years years, $diff.months months and $diff.days days"
```

To print `0 years, 11 months and 29 days`.

If you're using Java 7 with Groovy, you could use [JodaTime in a very similar way](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-time-elapsed-in-days-hours-minutes-seconds/)

```
@Grab('joda-time:joda-time:2.7')
import org.joda.time.*

int totalDays = 364

Period diff = LocalDate.now().with { now ->
    new Period(now, now.plusDays(totalDays), PeriodType.yearMonthDay())
}

println "$diff.years years, $diff.months months and $diff.days days"
```

Comment: 365 gives 11 months and 30 days, and I need 1 year :)

Comment: @Gwalk but February next year is a leap year, so has 29 days.  (ie: one year from today is 366 days away, not 365)

Comment: Yes, I understand, but there isn't something like this in statistics. Every month has 30 days, every year has 365 days.

Comment: You can't have it all ways unfortunately. If you say 30 days in a month, then you get 360 days in a year... You can't have a sensible answer that shows 365 days as a year and 30 days as a month... Not that I can see anyway

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do  this just one month variable directly. My advice is;

Define your month as an array with length of 12. Put every months day count differently in this array. Loop over on this array to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Months have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days. So, **if you don't have a `startDate` to check dates between days** what you have to do is create a rule to avoid error margin during months.

One easy way i can find is to sum + 1 in each even month (except december that is the remaining) like:

```
MONTH 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11 
DAYS  30  31  30  31  30  31  30  31  30  31  30 = 335 + x days left..
```

This will fix your calculation, but you will face a problem. This number, since you don't have start or end date, won't be real, **31 days can be just 1 month (December), or 1 month (February) + 3 days (from March or January)**.